# Google Map javascript api key

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I am using a cordova application and have a browser key for map.

```
<script async defer

        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBHJxzPHD_egYnhxntqcvfem35YRjruzAg&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

but I want to take my key from server , I took and I store this key as

```
localStorage.getItem("MapCode")
```

this locastorage gives

> "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBHJxzPHD_egYnhxntqcvfem35YRjruzAg&callback=initMap"

so I want to write this to src but I couldn't do it.

```
<script async defer

            src=localStorage.getItem("MapCode")>
    </script>
```

How can I solve this?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load Google Maps JavaScript API dynamically. For this purpose you can create the following code:

```
function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = localStorage.getItem("MapCode");
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

Please look at the sample code http://jsbin.com/carobun/edit?html,output

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
    var c = new google.maps.LatLng(54.8867537,-1.557352);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom:7,
        center: c
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
 
function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3' +
        '&key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: I do not see any mention of the async and defer keywords the solution. Are these accounted for in any way or are they assumed to not be important in the answer? Asking to learn. Thank you!